# Octave-online.net vpa((pi-1),100) strange result?

Tags: octave

in [octave-online.net](https://octave-online.net/#cmd=vpa((pi-1)%2C100)) the vpa() function returns me the non precise result. If i try some computation with a lot digits behind decimal after 49's digit is the result zero. Is there some trick how to compute with a lot digits behind decimal?

`vpa((pi-1),100)`

returns:

`2.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I have similar problem for similar inputs with different length(e.g. `vpa((113/111),100)`)

Thank You.

trying:
`vpa((pi-1),100)`

expecting:
2.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `vpa((p-1),100)` the calculation of `pi-1` is done using limited precision and the (imprecise) result is then applied to the `vpa` function.

Instead, the `vpa` function needs to make the calculation:

```
   vpa('pi-1',100)
```

giving the expected result:

```
2.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068
```

See more details on the [`vpa` reference](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/vpa.html) page.